# 2x2 Matrices and Differences of Fractions

Tags: matrices, soft-question, fractions

Consider the difference of two arbitrary fractions, $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$.
$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$
The numerator is the determinant of the 2x2 matrix $$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & c \\
b & d \\ \end{array} \right)$$
Is there any reason for this? Are the two related in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of the determinant as an [expression for an area or volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant) spanned by the vectors $(a,b)^T$ and $(c,d)^T$. If the ratios, which represent the direction of the vector are equal, i.e. $a/b=c/d$, then the area/volume is $0$.